# Is there any way to replace "move"?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

The "move" command can't use because the account system is gone. So, Is there any way to manage my coins, address, wallet with no fee like "move"? Pleas let me know. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use separate wallets.

Bitcoin Core now supports loading multiple wallets simultaneously.

This isn't an exact replacement; you can't transfer between those wallets at zero cost. But on the other hand, the coins are actually physically separated, rather than being virtual bean counters within one wallet.

Comment: So I only have one way? You're just saying that it's a way to import all the private keys of all the addresses into your new wallet, right?

Comment: @ahwon: That's not how I interpreted Pieter's answer. Be careful importing private keys because you'll need to understand how that affects backup requirements and use of previously backed-up private keys or recovery phrases (for those wallet apps that support them). Getting this wrong can cause financial loss.  See [GUI Support for Multiwallet Feature](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/bitcoin-core-0180-release-heres-whats-new)

Comment: @ahwon That's if you need a replacement at all. The alternative is implementing the account logic in your application. "accounts" in Bitcoin Core were just virtual counters: one wallet balance, with shared coins, but remembering how much of it belongs to which account. If you actually need something like that, you can also do the accounting outside of Bitcoin Core.

Comment: @ahwon And no, I'm talking about actually having distinct wallets (not just distinct addresses). Instead of having multiple accounts, you would create one wallet per account.

Comment: @PieterWuille  Now I fully understand. Thank you so much.